# View a document TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to TKinter and cant seem to find any examples on how to view a document in a window. What I am trying to accomplish is that when selecting a PDF or TIF it will open the file and show the first page in a window using TKinter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time has passed since this question was posted but, for those still looking for a solution, here's one I've found :

https://github.com/rk700/PyMuPDF/wiki/Demo:-GUI-script-to-display-a-PDF-using-wxPython-or-Tkinter

Basically, it uses PyMuPDF, a python binding for MuPDF. MuPDF is a lightweight document viewer capable of displaying a few file formats, such as pdf and epub.

I quote the code used for TKinter:

This demo can easily be adopted to Tkinter. You need the imports

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

and do the following to display each PDF page image:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# MuPDF code
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
pix = doc.getPagePixmap(pno - 1)      # create pixmap for a page

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Tkinter code
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
self.img = Image.frombytes("RGBA",
                       [pix.width, pix.height],
                       str(pix.samples))
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.img.size[0]+20, 
            height=self.img.size[1]+20)
canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.photo)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: The link above sadly seems to have been deprecated. I was a having a problem with Pixmap on another library and I think there's some more central issue there. I'm too new to really understand how to hunt down the real issue <3

Comment: Try:
https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is impossible my friend!

Try using snippets from this:
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/extracting_jpgs_from_pdfs.html 
to convert the pdf to an image.
I would then display the image on a label using PIL and Tkinter.

And I think Tif files should display on a label without problems IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to show a TIF or PDF in a Tkinter window. Your main options are to show plain text, and to show images (.gif with plain Tkinter, other formats if you include PIL - the python imaging library).

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses the old library `pypdfocr` (I had to modify it to work with Python 3) and [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) (Ghostscript needs to be installed outside of Python and so isn't ideal for software to be distributed) to convert each of the PDF's pages into an image that can then be opened by PIL. In the sense that it uses very old libraries and packages, [DrD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423323/7496549) is probably more appropriate.

```
import glob
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
import pypdfocr.pypdfocr_gs as pdfImg

files = glob.glob(pdfImg.PyGs({}).make_img_from_pdf(file_name)[1])
pages = [PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(file)) for file in files]
```